# application crashes even before launch

Tags: android, performance, android-emulator

Hi i made some changes to my already made applicaation ... and  now it fails immediately aafter laaunching ..

here is the log entry details :

```
08-21 06:01:58.726: D/AndroidRuntime(782): Shutting down VM
08-21 06:01:58.756: W/dalvikvm(782): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
08-21 06:01:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(782): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 06:01:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(782): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{hellog.diwesh.NugaBest/helog.diwesh.NugaBest.NUGA_HealthCareActivity_Intro}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "helog.diwesh.NugaBest.NUGA_HealthCareActivity_Intro" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/hellog.diwesh.NugaBest-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/hellog.diwesh.NugaBest-2, /system/lib]]
08-21 06:01:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
08-21 06:01:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-21 06:01:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-21 06:01:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-21 06:01:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-21 06:01:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-21 06:01:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-21 06:01:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 06:01:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-21 06:01:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-21 06:01:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-21 06:01:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-21 06:01:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(782): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "helog.diwesh.NugaBest.NUGA_HealthCareActivity_Intro" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/hellog.diwesh.NugaBest-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/hellog.diwesh.NugaBest-2, /system/lib]]
08-21 06:01:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
08-21 06:01:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-21 06:01:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-21 06:01:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
08-21 06:01:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
08-21 06:01:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(782):  ... 11 more
08-21 06:02:36.656: I/Process(782): Sending signal. PID: 782 SIG: 9
```

Comment: have you declared the new class in your manifest? If so, check whether the class name is mentioned correctly or not.

Comment: Your package name is hellog.diwesh.NugaBest or helog.diwesh.NugaBest?

Comment: Please post the manifest

Answer (score 8):

If you develop with Eclipse, go to Java build path / order export and put all your specific libraries FIRST.

This fixes the issue.

Comment: Had a similar problem. This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you add the new class`NUGA_HealthCareActivity_Intro` in your manifest?

Comment: so maybe the activity is still declared in your manifest. You have to delete it!

Answer (score 0):

Your exception says,

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "helog.diwesh.NugaBest.NUGA_HealthCareActivity_Intro" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/hellog.diwesh.NugaBest-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/hellog.diwesh.NugaBest-2, /system/lib]]`

Which means you are trying to access class `helog.diwesh.NugaBest.NUGA_HealthCareActivity_Intro` but Android's class loader cannot find this class.

This class is not present in your eclipse code as well as the jar libraries kept in libs directory

Is this class being referred from a library jar?
Try replacing the library jar with the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your manifest, likely this,
check your package name and class name, it might be not same..
your this activity is unreacheable, check it,
`helog.diwesh.NugaBest.NUGA_HealthCareActivity_Intro`

**EDIT**

Change your `lib` folder name to `libs`,